# Add block to product_type_data

Tags: magento, layout

Hy,
I'm writing a custom module and I 'would like to add custom block to the app/design/frontend/mytemplate/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml

I'cannot use the extra data place holder so I've to modify the default.phtm where I've added this code:

```
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('msgdisp') ?>
```

in my module layout.xml I've written the following section:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <layout version="1.0.0">
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="??????">
        <block type="core/template" name="msgdisp" as="msgdisp" template="msgdisp/messaggiodisp.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

I'don't figure out what I've to put instead of ??????, so far I've tried:

product_type_data

product.info.simple

but no one of the above as worked.

In the messaggiodisp.phtml I've written a simple "placeholder" code

```
<!-- Hello World -->
```

please let me know what I'm doing wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found a solution, I was wrong in the xml file:

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
<reference name="product.info.simple">
    <block type="core/template" name="msgdisp" as="msgdisp" template="msgdisp/messaggiodisp.phtml"/>
</reference>
```